# Using the upload method for Vimeo uploads, name and description discarded, video ID is alphanumeric

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I am using an HTTP call to upload a video using a public URL of a zoom recording. The upload is working, BUT

1. The name and description, even though supplied in the API call are discarded apparently in the result.
2. The video ID generated seems to be alphanumeric whereas the video ID is clearly stated in the specs as an integer value. Interestingly enough when using the vimeo app in Integromat I can get a number video ID but when using the Upload API with the upload link it generates a non standard video ID which if course is not accepted by the the vimeo app.

Here's an example Vimeo link I get to the video

https://vimeo.com/640201271/b99c5d6405

the b99... part is nonstandard for some reason.

The Upload API for videos using the link parameter docs:

[Vimeo API Reference: Videos | Vimeo Developer](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/videos#upload_video)

My payload for the https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos call:

```
     "data": "{  
     
     "upload": 
     
        {
     "approach": "pull", 
     "name": "Alex Sirota's Personal Meeting Room - alex@newpathconsulting.com - 0", 
     "description": "Recording Start Date/Time: 2021-10-28 09:55 PM - Recording End Date/Time: 2021-10-28 09:55 PM - Duration (min): 0", 
     "privacy.download": false,  
     "privacy.embed": "private", 
     "privacy.view":"nobody",  
     "size": "784755",  
     "link": "https://us02web.zoom.us/rec/download/redacted?access_token=redacted" 
        }
    }"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-public videos will sometimes have an alphanumeric video id - it's highly recommended to use the "metadata.interactions" objects on the Video response to interact with the video, especially if you're interacting with private videos https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/responses/video.

If you'd like this video to be available publicly on the Vimeo app, you would need to ensure to set the `privacy.view` = 'anybody' on upload (this will also remove the alphanumeric video id).

Comment: I set the privacy.view to 'anybody' and the video is still being uploaded as unlisted and thus with the alphanumeric video ID
{
  "upload": {
  "approach": "pull",
     "privacy.download": false,
    "privacy.embed": "private",
    "privacy.view":"anybody",
   }
}

The API response shows this

"privacy": {
                "view": "unlisted",
                "embed": "whitelist",
                "download": false,
                "add": true,
                "comments": "nobody"
            },

Comment: Your fields are a bit off - when the documentation refers to `privacy.view`, it means an object with key "privacy" and a field "view",


{

  "upload": { 

     "approach": "pull"

  }, 

  "privacy": {

    "view": "anybody",

    "embed": "private" (... add other privacy fields)

  }

}

Comment: Well look at that, I was reading the docs verbatim and you're right. That little snippet in their docs do show the object with the keys...

{
  "upload": {
    "approach": "tus",
    "size": 800000000
  },
  "name": "My Video",
  "privacy": { "view": "nobody" }
}

Comment: Aaron, you are absolutely correct. Uploading with the "privacy": {"view": "anybody"} yielded a regular Vimeo ID (numeric)  which then can be used elsewhere. I'll just make another call to make it private afterwards with another API call. Thank you!

Comment: Looking at the URL format further on unlisted video the Video ID is actually the second alphanumeric item so parsing that out will allow you to modify the Video just fine. So

https://vimeo.com/640201271/b99c5d6405

the 640201271 on this privacy.view=unlisted video is the actual video ID, and it can be manipulated with this number just fine.

Comment: @AlexSirota can you please let me know any way to access this kind of private URLs anyway?

I also have similar requirements for vimeo layer URLs like,
https://vimeo.com/{end_path_1}/{end_path_2}

Comment: Hi Jay, I don’t think I understand your question. If you have an app in Vimeo with the right scope you can call any video and manage it as long as you have access to it.